# cellForRowAtIndexPath lagging issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath I set a text of one of my UILabel's with the following:

```
cell.detail.text = [[poll objectForKey:@"parent"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

However, this causes the cell to lag as I scroll up and down the cell and this is only for the first time. After I finish scrolling from the top to the bottom for the very first time(this is the laggy part) and try to do it again for the second time (scroll from top to bottom). This doesn't lag. Why is this? Here is my full code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VSCustomCell";
    VSCustomCell * cell = (VSCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VSCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (VSCustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }


    [cell.main setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"cafeta" size:14]];
    [cell.detail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bebas" size:8.0]];
    [cell.detail setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    PFObject * poll;

    [cell.stats setHidden:NO];
    [cell.stats setEnabled:YES];
    [cell.stats addTarget:self action:@selector(stats:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.stats setTag:indexPath.row];

    poll = [self.spotsResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (poll){
        cell.main.text = [poll objectForKey:@"question"];
        cell.detail.text = [[poll objectForKey:@"parent"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }      
    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: How many rows are in your table? If you're convinced that it's the objectForKey methods that are slow, you may need to post some code from your `PFObject` class. Also, all of your setFont and setHidden stuff can go inside the if cell == nil statement unless it gets changed elsewhere in the code.

Comment: How complicated is VSCustomCell? Meaning how many subview it has? lagging of custom cells with many uiviews is a common problem and there are several solutions if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling becomes fast later means cells are getting reused. Which is good sign.
So the problem is in 1st phase, i.e in creating cell section if(cell==nil){}. Try creating the xib for cell again (don't forget to add reuse identifier for cell in xib) .

Comment: if that is the case ,then why if I comment out the dictionary of dictionary code from above it becomes fast?

Comment: also what do you mean by reuse identifier for cell in xib? some code would help

Comment: I also checked that it only creates 4 cell and then the rest is reuse, when reusing it, it is also still slow